# jquery- can not retrieve data from object type response which I get through ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, spring-boot

I have a page for a table. I am trying to get data from api by ajax call and retrieve that data and trying to show it in the table of the page.
So , I need key and value both. I want to set key as a column name ( header for column ) and value for row.

But I can't retrieve my data from the response and can not bind it in the html page.

**Here is my Controller:**

```
 public ResponseEntity<Object> findPaginated(
        @RequestParam("page") int page, @RequestParam("size") int size) throws NotFoundException {

    JsonParser parser = new BasicJsonParser();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    ApiResponse response = new ApiResponse(false);
    Page<EmployeeDesignation> resultPage = designationService.findPaginated(page, size);
    List<EmployeeDesignation> parseList = resultPage.getContent();
    response.setSuccess(parser.parseList(String.valueOf(parseList)));
    headers.add("totalelement", String.valueOf(resultPage.getTotalElements()));
    headers.add("totalpages", String.valueOf(resultPage.getTotalPages()));
    System.err.println ( " in controller ");
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .headers(headers)
            .body(response);

}
```

**This is my ajax call format ( .js file ) :**

```
function getList() {
                 $http({
                     url: "/api/designation/designations/get?",
                     method: 'GET',
                     params:{ page: 2, size: 2 }
                 }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                      let info = Object.values(response.data.data);
                      let check = Object.values(info);
                      console.log("keys::::" + check);
                      getArray(check);
                      }
                 , function errorCallback(data) { });};

      function getArray($products){
                  jQuery($products).each(function(i, obj) {
                      jQuery('div#check').append(obj.name + '::::::contains ::::::' +obj.designationRefId);
                     
                  });
      }
```

But when I append the data on page , it shows undefined.

**Here is my .json format file :**

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": null,
    "data": [
        "EmployeeDesignation{id=75928ab9-7c97-442d-b777-dc32ca9ef49d, version=0, refId=0, designationRefCode='2', name='programmer'}",
        "EmployeeDesignation{id=57305c1f-bca0-4a56-ba19-5784c4461f5b, version=0, refId=0, designationRefCode='2', name='designer'}"
    ]
}
```

**This the output of of: console.log( JSON.stringyfy(response)):**

```
 {"data":{"success":true,"message":null,"data":["EmployeeDesignation{id=75928ab9-7c97-442d-b777-dc32ca9ef49d, version=0, refId=0, designationRefCode='2', name='programmer'}","EmployeeDesignation{id=57305c1f-bca0-4a56-ba19-5784c4461f5b, version=0, refId=0, designationRefCode='2', name='designer'}"]},"status":200,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"/api/designation/designations/get?","params":{"page":2,"size":2},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"","xhrStatus":"complete"}
```

**How can I solve this matter? How can I bind these data on table ???**

Comment: Hi, can you show output of `response` ?

Comment: the json format, which I have given - this is the output of java API. and now I am giving u the output of console.log(JSON.stringify(response)),please see the edit version @Swati

Comment: check if the json which you are getting is valid json . Also , use `JSON.parse` to parse your json receieve from backend before accessing them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems converting the list into string is generating this format.

You can try any of the two,

1. During showing the data remove the "EmployeeDesignation" from each array element.

Or,

2. Make the JSON Object of your own without converting to String.